# grid view shows only one row and other rows are shown scroll

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a scroll view with some textviews and a grid view. But only one row of grid view is displayed and others apper on scroll. This is my xml file.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="false"

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/picker1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Welcome,"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Guest"
        android:textColor="@color/accentColor"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/welcome" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextCity"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
        android:id="@+id/editTextCity"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Nagpur"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextCity"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSearchName"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Your Search"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:background="@color/primaryColorDark"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSearchName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <GridView
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSearch"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Please help me. I want that whole page should scroll.

Comment: you only have one gridview in your code...

Comment: It's not good practice to add one scrollable content inside other scrollable content.Here you have added GridView inside ScrollView which creates problem in scrolling.

Comment: @Nitesh So how to do this then?

Comment: You can display your ImageView,TextView,EditText,Button,etc. above the GridView and remove the ScrollView from your code.It will scroll your Grid's content and other portions will remain as it is.I think its better instead of scrolling whole page.

Comment: @Nitesh Thanks but I want whole page scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You Should not use Gird/List View inside Scrollview, since it has already scrollview. Better you can create a header with all the views and add to Listview/Grid view.